# Set sort order on images

Tags: c#, datagridview, foreach

I ran into a problem that I've been banging my head on for weeks...

I've came up with a solution that is terrible and extremely long and embarrassing.
Now I wonder if I can get some professional help from you :)

I'm trying to loop through a datagridview and set a order for for my images.
My in-data is a datagridview that has two columns (id, sortorder)

The problem is that my in-data sortorder is 1 for first image and 2 for last image and allot of value 0 that should be in between
So I want to convert these values:

```
id     sortorder
9520   1
9520   0
9520   0
9520   0
9520   0
9520   2
```

To this:

```
id     sortorder
9520   1 (original was 1)
9520   2
9520   3
9520   4
9520   5
9520   6 (original was 2)
```

EDIT:
The code I got so far is this:

```html
                void setSort()
    {
        dgv2.ColumnCount = 5;
        dgv2.Columns[0].Name = "PropertyID";
        dgv2.Columns[1].Name = "Type";
        dgv2.Columns[2].Name = "Status";
        dgv2.Columns[3].Name = "ImageName";
        dgv2.Columns[4].Name = "Order";
        string id = dgv1[0, 0].Value.ToString();
        int sOrder = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells["PropertyID"].Value == null) break;
            string id2 = row.Cells["PropertyID"].Value.ToString();
            if (id2 != id) sOrder = 0;
            sOrder++;
            row.Cells["Type"].Value = sOrder;
            id = id2;
            dgv2.Rows.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), row.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), row.Cells[3].Value.ToString(), row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "-" + id + "." + row.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) You really should include your code.  2) If you have a working solution and just want advise about improving it you might be better served by posting the question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Why don't you loop over the rows and set the values in the 2nd column? Or are there more IDs and you want to restart the sortorder on each change? Which would take about as many line as it does to ask these questions..

Comment: Hi Juharr, Thank you for your answer. The code I wrote was so embarrassing and it didn't work, so I have deleted it...Can you please advise me how you should do if you should do something like this?

Comment: Hi TaW, the problem is that I have to change every value from 0 to a counter but still retain the order of the first and second image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this do the job?

```
void setSort()
{
    string id = dataGridView1[0, 0].Value.ToString();
    int sOrder = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1[0, row].Value == null) break;
        string id2 = dataGridView1[0, row].Value.ToString();
        if (id2 != id) sOrder = 0;
        sOrder++;
        dataGridView1[1, row].Value = sOrder;
        id = id2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you TaW, but the problem is that i need the image that has  sortorder 1 from the original to stay first in the "new" sortorder and that sortorder 2 from the original to get last in the "new" sortorder, As you can tell, I have some problems explaining my issue... :)

Comment: I've updated the question with the code I got so far :)

Comment: _I need the image that has sortorder 1 from the original to stay first in the "new" sortorder and that sortorder 2 from the original to get last in the "new" sortorder_ Well the code above does just that, have you tried it?

Comment: When I tried the code you provided, and every image is sorted correct, but it don't take consideration of the original sort order. If you take a look at this picture, the "Type" is the original sort order and the "Status" is the new sort order: [link](http://content.screencast.com/users/marcus.o/folders/Jing/media/95d3ff3e-e468-4e12-99e4-b2994c91da36/2014-12-03_1603.png) and the result I'm looking for is this: [link] (http://content.screencast.com/users/marcus.o/folders/Jing/media/a0dc2da6-72cf-4157-8b0c-36feeff8c8b6/2014-12-03_1608.png)

Comment: Ah, more columns coming into play. Now a DGV doesn't easily sort by more than one column __nor is it able to do a stable sort__. Imo the best solution is to create a special sort column, that holds all informtion needed. So, as far as I can see your edited code is going the right way. You do want to use the DGV sort? You are filling a 2nd DGV?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make the changes needed in the in-data instead, so now I'm able to use TaW's solution as it is :)
Thank you very much for all your assistance and patience